# Proper way of refering to yourself, according to graduate level

Tags: etiquette, presentation

I currently have a degree as a Master in Computer Sciences, and i was always wondering on how to call myself in a more "short" manner. For example, a PhD might introduce himself as a "Doctor" to other people, but how does a MSc call himself: "Master"? "Mister"? "MSc"?.

Talking to some PhD and MSC acquaintances, they had the same doubt about it, and i think this might be a good place to inquire about such topic, and i could not find another related question to answer myself.

Comment: As someone who works in software, I would hope you only consider using a title like that within academia. Using a title like that on your résumé to apply to a software job will likely get you laughed at.

Comment: Perhaps, but the scope of this question is focused on academia, rather than workplace.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While my Internet search has come up sparse, I think most etiquette guides suggest that you do not refer to yourself with honorifics. There are some exceptions where the honorific carries immediate pertinent information. For example, it might be acceptable for a medical doctor walking in a exam room to introduce herself as "Dr. Jane Doe", to indicate their role in the relationship, although I prefer "Your doctor Jane Doe" since it clearly separates honorific from role.

As for how to refer to an individual with a masters degree, there is no associated honorific.

Comment: Well, for example, my previous advisor was trying to get a certain information from a gov't institution under the name "XXX", and was once turned down. Then, someone "recommended" her to address herself as "Dr XXX" (to add the "Dr" part to her name) and VOILA, the process went smoother as a baby's tush. Of course my motivation is not to get such treatment, but it would be good to know how to "shorten" my degree at one point.

Comment: While writing that comment, i remembered an scene on TBBT (The Big Bang Theory), where the head chief of the lab addressed every one of the protagonists (Dr Cooper, Dr Hofstader, Dr Koothrapalli, MISTER Hollowitz), but "Mister" sounds kind of "not that proper".

Answer (score 29):

According to proper etiquette you may use *Master* as a title (as in “Master Segovia”) if and only if you are:

- the heir apparent of a Scottish viscount or baron
- a boy not old enough to be called “Mr.”

The *New Oxford American Dictionary* (which gives the above information) also lists the archaic use as a  “title for a man of high rank or learning”, but (a) that is archaic, (b) it was not linked to a specific degree, just a courtesy title.

**There is no formal title** in British English or American English to designate someone who holds a Master's degree. *Get over it, and earn a PhD! :)*

Comment: As of now, i'm currently assessing if getting a PhD would be a wise move on my carreer (as my advisor's fellow PhD said to me once: "If your heart is not into it, even not 100% into it, don't pursue a PhD"), but that's another question altogether, out of the scope of this "discussion". Thanks for the encouragement though :).

Answer (score 3):

You would not address yourself as 'Master so-and-so' but there are circumstances where is it not inappropriate to include your graduate degree with your name; 'So and So, MSc'. The obvious examples of this type of use are publications and presentations.

Comment: ...depending on your field.  In some fields (like mine), including your degree in a paper or presentation would be considered gauche.

Comment: +JeffE, it does depend on the field somewhat. In the information security field it's not uncommon to see signature blocks or attribution lines that read like a mini-resume but I suspect that it is highly variable. I think that this is also going out of style somewhat.